# Old anime about two brothers fighting in a Gotham-like city; one of them has a sword with a red ribbon on it

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this anime a long time ago. It has a pretty dark theme, set in a Gotham-like city, and the relationship between the two brothers is like that of Itachi and Sasuke from *Naruto*.

The older brother made himself hated by his younger brother, but actually loves him. The younger brother has a sword with a red ribbon on it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, was this a movie or a series, and did it include any science fiction or fantasy elements?

Comment: is it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_of_the_Stranger ??

Comment: @LogicDictates I think it was released in 90's based on the animation and design. The story may be about 2 brothers or friends.

Comment: Could this be X { https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_(TV_series) }?  It's about 2 friends (close as brothers), and when the hero chooses to become "good" his brother automatically turns "evil".  They end up on opposing sides and have battles within a city (where somehow magical barriers appear and prevent civilians being affected).  They both have swords and I seem to recall a red ribbon (but could be wrong).